# Can we reduce size even more of Jpg, gif, png even after saving images using "Save as web" option of Photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, xhtml

Can we reduce size even more of Jpg, gif, png even after saving images using "Save as web" option of Photoshop?

[image]

Without losing much quality? Or Save for web is enough? Do images keep any other information which can't be removed from "save as web" option?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you're trying to ask... Do you want to know what Save for web does or do you want to know how to best save images to use them on the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools such as [PNG crush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) that can reduce the file size of images (in this case, PNGs). However, from experience, it rarely saves anything on files saved from Photoshop. Perhaps PS uses PNG crush or its own algorithms to make the file size as small as possible when you save it.

So don't worry about it, just save from Photoshop and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to find minimum acceptable quality for your needs. I mean resolution and optimization ratio. Less size less quality.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest slicing your images into regions based on their overall color content, and the applying the best compression settings to the individual slices. Without slicing the image, one setting applies to the whole image, and that it may not be optimal for the color range of the image.

For example, your sample image can be sliced into 3 sections - the shaded text overlay and the two borders. The overlay slice can be compressed with gif, and the borders can be compressed with jpeg, at whatever quality settings look the best.

Answer (score 0):

For decreasing file sizes of jpg images I always use [xat Image Optimizer](http://www.xat.com/io/). Saves me on average ~20% after saving it for web with photoshop.